# Taming more than one Pokémon per battle?

Tags: pokemon-conquest

I am considering using the Eevee password in *Pokémon Conquest* to get more of them for my hero. As this password unleashes a swarm of Eevee, is it possible to link with more than one Pokémon per battle?

Comment: Thanks for that edit and making a tag for it. So much simpler!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot link with multiple Pokémon in one battle. And what password do you have for more eevee??

Comment: http://serebii.net/conquest/passwords.shtml This has all the currently released passwords. English versions are at the bottom.